# Dojo hide an image

Tags: javascript, dojo

I can successfully create the image.

```
var tgImage = surface.createImage({width:9,height:13,src:tgimageurl,id:"hideimage"});
```

I want to fade it out using the fade out method:-

```
tgImage.connect('onclick', function(){fx.fadeOut({ id: hideimage }).play(););
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Not fading? Throwing error? Chances are it has to do with the scope of your onclick event

Answer (score 0):

`dojo/fx` operates on HTML DOM nodes. You can’t use it to modify gfx objects. Also, gfx IDs are different from DOM IDs. There is no API for “fading out” an image within a gfx surface.